# How to query firebase realtime database to get last month data

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

How to query data last month or last 2 months based on the timestamp in snapshot this is the question, know I have been able to do that in Firestore like this

```
useEffect(() =>{
  const fetchData = async () => {
  
  const today = new Date()
  const lastMonth = new Date(new Date().setMonth(today.getMonth() - 1))
  const prevMonth = new Date(new Date().setMonth(today.getMonth() - 2))
  
  const lastMonthQuery = query(collection(db,'users'), where('since', '<=', today), where('since', '>', lastMonth))
  
  const lastMonthData = await getDocs(lastMonthQuery)
  
  }
  fetchData()
},[])
```

how can i write query like this in realtime database? i have tried this code and this is how my database look like

[image]

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchData = async () =>{
      const today = new Date()
      const lastMonth = new Date(new Date().setMonth(today.getMonth() - 1))
      const prevMonth = new Date(new Date().setMonth(today.getMonth() - 2))

      try{
        const dbRef = query(ref(database, 'users/since'), startAt(lastMonth), endAt(today));
        const last = await get(dbRef)
        console.log(last)

         }catch(err){
          console.log(err)
        }
      }
      fetchData()
    },[])
```

in the console i got this

> Error: Query: When ordering by priority, the first argument passed to startAt(), startAfter() endAt(), endBefore(), or equalTo() must be a valid priority value (null, a number, or a string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code won't work:

```
query(ref(database, 'users/since'), startAt(lastMonth), endAt(today));
```

This creates a reference to `/users/since` (which doesn't exist in your screenshot) and then filters them on an implicit value called priority.

What you want to do instead is run a query on `/users` and filter the data on `since`, which you can do by passing `orderByChild` to the query:

```
query(ref(database, 'users'), orderByChild('since'), startAt(lastMonth), endAt(today));
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [ordering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data), which you should always do before filtering it.

Comment: i don't know why but when adding **endAt(today)**  i get this in console `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't._freezeSettings')`

Comment: and without **endAt()** I get `DataSnapshot {_node: ChildrenNode, ref: ReferenceImpl, _index: PathIndex} (main.be9c1e84eef02a6dc4de.hot-update.js, line 123)`

Comment: The original problem you posted was caused by missing an `orderBy` statement. Does that make sense based on my explanation, and is that problem now gone? --- If you have further problems and can't figure them out by searching, please post a new question for that so that others can also help.

Comment: even your answer doesn't solve the problem but if you don't want to help any more thanks anyway

Comment: "doesn't solve the problem" is hard to help with. What error do you get when you add an `orderByChild(...)` call as I showed in my answer? If that is a different error, and no longer related to being able to execute the query due to invalid values in your conditions, it means that my answer addressed the error you got.

Comment: Mr. Frank the question is not about the error my question is **How to query firebase realtime database to get last month data** `orderByChild(...)` doesn't get the job done

Comment: What error do you get when you add an `orderByChild(...)` call as I showed in my answer?

Comment: Frank, you are a firebase expert I don't know if you work with them but still, the question is about querying the firebase realtime database based on the timestamp in snapshots, `query(ref(database, 'users'), orderByChild('since'), startAt(lastMonth), endAt(today));` this query doesn't work **console.log** shows `null` when printing `console.log(last.val())` there is no value, when printing `console.log(last)` there is this `DataSnapshot {_node: ChildrenNode, ref: ReferenceImpl, _index: PathIndex}` i don't know what to do next, your answer is excepted but I came here for a solution.

Comment: the problem was that the timestamp that react native giving is 13 digits and in the firebase is 10 digits this took all my day there is no error it just don't match